# IOS/Objective-C: UIActivityViewController Not Showing Twitter

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

For some reason Twitter is not showing in my UIActivityViewController although I have the twitter app installed and am logged in.  It is not an excluded type.

The iphone SE is running ios 10.3.1

Just once, twitter did appear but now it is no longer appearing.  Almost every other app you can think of such as email, facebook, sms, snapchat, linked is appearing so am stumped on what could be causing this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

I am using the protocol `UIActivityItemSource` and the delegate method below that supposedly helps IOS figure out which applications to show as options.  I have tried this with a string and nil but can't get Twitter to show.  When I set it to string, facebook stops appearing possibly because facebook no longer wants you to pre-fill the message or subject fields.

```
-(id)activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem:(UIActivityViewController *)activityViewController placeholderForActivityType:(NSString *)activityType
{
    NSLog(@"DELEGATE METHOD CALLED for Placeholder");
    //The point of this seems to be to set the data type.  
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: check it out https://twittercommunity.com/t/bug-in-ios-11/91490

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did this, but in case..

Have you tried this:
[image]

[image]

**BTW!!!**
While I was doing these screenshots I noticed that twitter didn't appear at first. Then I turned Twitter on (so that it is loaded into memory). And then it appeared in the sharing options.

Comment: Twitter does not show up in the list.  I tried loading it into memory first and then launching the activityviewcontroller but no change.  Wondering if it has something to do with placeholder in the delegate method.  Apparently IOS uses placeholder to guess which applications are appropriate.  I have tried it with a string and nil, however, which I would think would work for Twitter and no go.  If I use a string, Facebook does not show, possibly because facebook no longer wants you to pre-fill text fields

Comment: I doubt but maybe you set the `excludedActivityTypes` property somewhere maybe?

Comment: Cuz as I see there even is a type: `UIActivityType.postToTwitter`